# How do I Update DataSet with update sql, then Udate the database in C sharp

Tags: c#

How do I Update DataSet with update sql, then Udate the database in C sharp. I have so code it does something but does not actually update the database. I feel I am really close to figuring this out, but I am missing something or I am not doing something right. my code is below if someone can see what it is I am not doing please let me know, I have been looking at this for the past 7 hours and can't figure it out.

```
            {   DataSet oDS = new DataSet();
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=StaffAs.accdb;");
        conn.Open();

        // Create the DataTable "SAssign" in the Dataset and the OrdersDataAdapter
       // UPDATE StaffAssignment SET StaffID = 4 WHERE (StaffID = 2)
        OleDbDataAdapter oOrdersDataAdapter = new  OleDbDataAdapter(new OleDbCommand("SELECT *     FROM StaffAssignment", conn));
        OleDbCommandBuilder oOrdersCmdBuilder = new  OleDbCommandBuilder(oOrdersDataAdapter);
        oOrdersDataAdapter.FillSchema(oDS, SchemaType.Source);
oOrdersDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand(String.Format("UPDATE StaffAssignment SET StaffID = 4 WHERE (StaffID = 2)"));
        DataTable pTable = oDS.Tables["Table"];
        pTable.TableName = "UpdateStaffA";

        oOrdersDataAdapter.Fill(pTable);

        try
        {
            oOrdersDataAdapter.Update(pTable);

        }
        catch (OleDbException e)
        { //Allows for update without violating interigty constainst
            return;
        }
        conn.Close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with your code, just give it a try:

```
 try
 {
      oOrdersDataAdapter.Update(oDS, "Table");

 }
 catch (OleDbException e)
 { 
      //Allows for update without violating interigty constainst
      return;
 }
```

Comment: Ok I see what you meant, it works great thank you so much :) That solves my problem. Sleep here I come. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Update methods updates just rows that their RowState is Equal to modified

setting all rowState to DataRowState.Modified and calling the update method will help you

Answer (score -1):

After you run the update, do this:

```
pTable.Clear()
oOrdersDataAdapter.Fill(pTable);
```

That will requery the database and return the new results.

Comment: Give it a shot and will let you know. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work, it throws an InvalidOperationException saying Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.